# Emscripten C++ to WASM with Classes - "error: undefined symbol"

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I have a really simple C++ project (removed as much code til the problem is still there.) Running `em++` is always leading to an error, `error: undefined symbol`

`main.cpp`

```c++
#include "edgeguard.hpp"

int main()
{
    EdgeGuardConfig core = EdgeGuardConfig::BuildEdgeGuard();
}
```

`edgeguard.cpp`

```c++
#include "edge-guard.hpp"

EdgeGuardConfig EdgeGuardConfig::BuildEdgeGuard()
{
}
```

`edgeguard.hpp`

```c++
class EdgeGuardConfig
{
public:
    static EdgeGuardConfig BuildEdgeGuard();
};
```

The command I'm using is `em++ ./main.cpp --std=c++17 -o ~/edgeguard-wasm/edgeguard-ft90x.html`

The results are always the same:

```
error: undefined symbol: _ZN15EdgeGuardConfig14BuildEdgeGuardEv (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: Link with `-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
warning: __ZN15EdgeGuardConfig14BuildEdgeGuardEv may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
em++: error: '/home/nessdan/code/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin/node /home/nessdan/code/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/src/compiler.js /tmp/tmpqwnlcp5h.json' failed (returned 1)
```

Some other things I've tried:

1. Using EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
2. Wrapping things in `extern "C"`
3. Running with `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0` (command finishes, but HTML output logs the error in my console when I open it.)
4. Running with `-s LINKABLE=1 -s EXPORT_ALL=1` - nothing changes, console output is the same.

I'm using the latest version of emscripten (`3.1.6`) and installed it fresh today (also installed and ran from my Windows computer with the exact same results.)

Comment: You never compile edgeguard.cpp ???

Comment: Can you expand Marc? The "main.cpp" function is all I would need - does the command I share not compile everything I would need (including "include" files?)

Comment: This isn't java, the C++ compiler doesn't try to guess that you might need a .cpp file just because you included a .hpp file with a similar name. Some IDEs / build systems might hide the details from you. You would get the same problem without wasm, if you tried to compile to native code using directly the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Marc Glisse's comment, I realize now that I needed to not just pass `main.cpp` but also all related `.cpp` files (I thought it would pick up that information from the includes ‍♂️)

It is now compiling